# Rails 4 Unpermited Parameters nested attribute curl test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl

Using rails 4.0.2
I'm having problem using curl to create an array of nested comments against a new blog Post.  I can use curl to create a new blog Post but I get "Unpermitted parameters:comments" in the log and no comments created when I try and create comments linked to the new post.

I've added an accepts_nested_attributes_for to the Post model and updated the post_params method in the post controller to accept comments_attributes.

I'd like to run curl against the app and create a new post and comments in the same call. Is there a problem in my curl call or have I missed something in my nested attributes setup?  Any advice appreciated.

This creates a new Post but not a comment:

```
curl -i -X POST -d 'post[title]=curlTest6 &post[comments][comment][commenter]=TestComment' http://localhost:3000/posts
```

Log for above call:

```
Processing by PostsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"post"=>{"title"=>"curlTest6 ", "comments"=>{"comment"=>{"commenter"=>"TestComment"}}}}
Unpermitted parameters: comments
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "posts" ("created_at", "title", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Mon, 09 Dec 2013 15:27:18 UTC +00:00], ["title", "curlTest6 "], ["updated_at", Mon, 09 Dec 2013 15:27:18 UTC +00:00]]
   (1.0ms)  commit transaction
```

**Comment Model**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

**Post Model**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, :allow_destroy => true



  validates :title, presence: true,
                      length: { minimum: 5 }

end
```

**Posts Controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:create]

  def new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
        redirect_to @post
      else
        render 'new'
    end
  end


  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    redirect_to posts_path
  end


  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  private
  def post_params
     params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text, comments_attributes:[:commenter, :body])
   end

end
```

**Comments Controller**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
      @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
      @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:commenter, :body))
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    end

    def destroy
       @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
       @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
       @comment.destroy
       redirect_to post_path(@post)
     end 
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off your `Comments` Controller is not going to be used here, only the `create` method of the `Posts` Controller. Controllers are for actions, not necessarily resources.

For these params:

```
{"post"=>{"title"=>"curlTest6 ", "comments"=>{"comment"=>{"commenter"=>"TestComment"}}}}
```

You'd strong-params them with:

```
params.require(:post).permit(:title, {comments: [ { comment: [ :commenter ] } ]})
```

Also note that for `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, usually you want the the parameter to be `:comments_attributes` and not `comments` and then not have another namespace (so no `comment`. Read more about this [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms).

```
params.require(:post).permit(:title, {comments_attributes: [ :commenter ]})
```

The curl request for that would be:

```
$ curl -i -X POST -d 'post[title]=curlTest6 &post[comments_attributes][][commenter]=TestComment' http://localhost:3000/posts
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I've updated the strong-params as you suggested and run the curl request.  It now returns an implicit conversion TypeError.    Parameters: {"post"=>{"title"=>"curlTest7 ", "comments_attributes"=>{"commenter"=>"TestComment"}}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):

Comment: I needed to update the curl call to : curl -i -X POST -d 'post[title]=curlTestx1 &post[comments_attributes][][commenter]=TestComment1&post[comments_attributes][][commenter]=TestComment2' http://localhost:3000/posts
   This creates a couple of Comments against the Post, exactly what I needed to test.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this because you need to be able to update the post to add additional comments? Perhaps this line in the controller's `update` method is the problem:

```
if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
```

Is it reasonable to change it to this:

```
if @post.update(post_params)
```